# How can I return an Iterator over a List of Mappings

Tags: java, testing, testng-dataprovider

The method looks like this. I just want to return an Object[]
 or an Object[][] or an Iterator< Object[]> with each row containing one of the three mappings that are created in for loop. I need all fields (category, usage, country) to be sent together.

```
@DataProvider(name = "NewListings")
public Iterator<Object[]> AddNewListings(){
    List<Map<String,String>> listings = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String,String> listing = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        listing.put("category", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));
        listing.put("usage", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));
        listing.put("country", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));

        listings.add(listing);
        //listing.clear();
    }

    Collection<Object[]> allListings = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(Map<String,String> map:listings){
        allListings.add(new Object[]{map});
    }

    return allListings.iterator();
}

@Test(dataProvider = "NewListings")
public void addListing(Map<String, String> field){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Are these all `String`s?

Comment: Yes they are all String.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing clear() on your listing item which means that when the for loop is done the listings list will contain one object and that object will contain the values generated last.
So change the method to this and it should work better

```
public List<Map<Object,Object>> AddNewListings(){
    List<Map<Object,Object>> listings = new ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        Map<Object,Object> listing = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        listing.put("category", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));
        listing.put("usage", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));
        listing.put("country", Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1));

        listings.add(listing);     
    }
    return listings;
}
```

And then you could map this into an array

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> result = AddNewListings();
List<Object> out = new ArrayList<>();

for(Map<Object, Object> item : result) {
    out.addAll(item.values());
}
Object[] allObjects2 = out.toArray();
```

Of course if it is only relevant to get an array of all the values then the AddNewListings method could be changed to

```
public Object[] AddNewListings2(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    Object[] listings = new Object[9];

    for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
        listings[i] = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(8)+1);     
    }
    return listings;
 }
```

Comment: That is indeed working better but I'm able to get only the last set of items from the most recent mapping doing this after the loop

    Collection<Object[]> allListings = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for(Map<String,String> map:listings){
            allListings.add(new Object[]{map});
        }
return allListings.iterator();

How could I get all separate sets of mappings? Return can't be applied anyway.

Comment: Sorry it is very unreadable so I edited the question with the extra code.

Comment: I am not quite sure I got what you meant but I'll change my code to deal with Object rather than String and an example how to convert to an Object[]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I finally got it to work as expected by adding invocationCount to @Test method and running several times from there.